# Lookup column lookups up link, not text

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

brand new oddity I have yet to see. I have two web parts, a picture library (projectPictures), and a list (projectProfile).

[image]

On ProjectPictures, I have a nonworking workflow (it is supposed to copy name to pictureName column). However, I changed the pictureName column (single line of text) to mimic the actual name. This way, on the project profile I can have a user select from the possible pictures for this project:
[image]

The issue I am running in to, is that the PictureName column of projectPictures is being looked up by the PictureName column in projectProfile, and instead of copying the text, it copied a link to edit that item. For example, if I click on the blue "acct" in projectProfile, it loads up the edit form for the acct.png in projectPictures. Ideas?
[image]